# Do I need @2x graphics for iPad apps?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, ios-simulator, ipad-2

I am making a universal app for the first time and I am wondering with the iPad if I need to include an @2x version of all my graphics like I do for iPhone apps or does the iPad not support that? i.e. if my background image is 1024 x 768 do I need a 2048 x 1536 @2x version?

Thanks

Comment: Google "ipad3" "retina display"

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/9611061/716216 and several others

Answer (score 3):

No, you don't.

But you might need it soon ;)

http://deallocatedobjects.com/posts/ipad-retina-images-found-in-itunes-u-and-ibooks-2-files

Answer (score 0):

No, the iPad 1 and iPad 2 offer a maximum screen resolution of 1024x768.

Answer (score 0):

No, the iPad 1 and iPad 2 have the same scene resolution of 1024 x 768. There is currently no "retina" iPad, so you do not need to worry about including "@2x" icons.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need them....

UNLESS you want to re-scale your (iPhone) graphics when an iPad user "zooms" the display. When the iPad  user changes the application zoom level, you can receive this notification:

```
_UIClassicApplicationWillChangeZoomNotificationName
```

And use the appropriate graphics, or on your views, layers, etc. set the drawing scale

```
// scale just changed!
CGFloat scale = [[_window screen] scale];
[layer setRasterizationScale:scale];
[layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
```

It's entirely optional. Some views have custom graphics that look terrible when scaled up on an iPad, this can fix that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since the third iPad generation is available now, which supports @2x resolution, you should integrate @2x graphics.